# Caml query in visual studio always returns all items in list. U2U Caml query builder returns correct results

Tags: sharepoint-addin, caml-query

I'm using the following query :

```
        camlQuery.set_viewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee'/><Value Type='User'>" + currentUser.get_title() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
      var listItemCollection = list.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(listItemCollection);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
        //alert("Success");

        var listItemEnumerator = listItemCollection.getEnumerator();

        if (listItemCollection.get_count() == 1 && listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
     }
```

This query returns ok results (count = 1) using the U2U Caml Query builder. When i use the code in visual studio it returns 2 results, all the items in the list.

What is wrong with my code?

I also tried query with ID but again returns all items.

```
        //camlQuery.set_viewXml = ("<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue :

Problem is using camlQuery.set_ViewXml with hardcoded the query.

If i use this it works :

```
var ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' LookupId='True'/><Value Type='Lookup'>" + _spPageContextInfo.userId + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

    //var ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee' LookupId='True'/<Value Type='Lookup'>" + currentUser.get_title() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

    camlQuery.set_viewXml(ViewXml);
```

Comment: The main reason is you were missing `(` and `)` brackets around the caml query (refer your question). Just update the line and it will work. No need to write two seperate lines. Try Below line, it will also work -- `camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Employee'/><Value Type='User'>" + currentUser.get_title() + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>");`